# Kivy App packaged with buildozer loads and then shows only a black screen

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

Currently im working on making this app with kivy, i am a noob so i thought this would be an easy place to start. the app is not finished but i wanted to try and get it working on my android phone... if only it was that easy. I am using buildozer through a virtual machine to package my app but it is constantly giving me a blanck screen and i dont know what to do. I'm not getting any errors in the logcat (at least that im aware of). What am i doing wrong? Thank you in advance for any help!

## main.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'systemanddock')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy_garden.mapview import MapView
import kivy.core.text
import webbrowser
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup



class StartScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SearchLocation(Screen):
    pass

    

class ERNearMe(Screen):
    pass

class PoliceNearMe(Screen):
    def button_on(self, **kwargs):
        self.ids.MapButton.source = 'MapMarker Button down.png' 

    def button_off(self, **kwargs):
        self.ids.MapButton.source = 'MapMarker Button up.png'


class EmergencyNumbers(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass



kv = Builder.load_file("crimewhereza.kv")

class CrimeWhereZA(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv
     


        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CrimeWhereZA().run()
```

## KV File

```
#:import App kivy.app
#:import Label kivy.uix.label
#:import Widget kivy.uix.widget
#:import FloatLayout kivy.uix.floatlayout
#:import Button kivy.uix.button
#:import Builder kivy.lang.builder
#:import ScreenManager kivy.uix.screenmanager
#:import Screen kivy.uix.screenmanager
#:import MapView kivy_garden.mapview
#:import CoreText kivy.core.text



WindowManager:
    StartScreen:
    SearchLocation:
    ERNearMe:
    PoliceNearMe:
    EmergencyNumbers:



<StartScreen>:
    name: "StartScreen"

    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:  
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                source: 'background 1.png'
        
        Button:
            text: "Search Location"
            background_normal: 'homescreen button normal.png'
            background_down: 'homescreen button down.png'
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5,"top": 0.90}
            size_hint: 0.22, 0.22
            font_size: 11
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "SearchLocation"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
            

        Button: 
            text: "ER Near Me"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5,"top": 0.70}
            background_normal: 'homescreen button normal.png'
            background_down: 'homescreen button down.png'
            size_hint: 0.22, 0.22
            font_size: 11
        
        Button: 
            text: "Police Station Near Me"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5,"top": 0.50}
            background_normal: 'homescreen button normal.png'
            background_down: 'homescreen button down.png'
            size_hint: 0.22, 0.22
            font_size: 11
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "PoliceNearMe"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
        
        Button: 
            text: "Emergency Numbers"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5,"top": 0.30}
            background_normal: 'homescreen button normal.png'
            background_down: 'homescreen button down.png'
            size_hint: 0.22, 0.22
            font_size: 11
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "EmergencyNumbers"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

<SearchLocation>:
    name: "SearchLocation"

    FloatLayout:


        Label:
            text: "Enter location:"
            pos_hint: {"x": -0.3, "y": -0.025}
            


        TextInput:
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5,"top": 0.5}
            size_hint: 0.40, 0.05
            id: searchloc
            multiline: False

        Button:
            id: srch
            text: "Search"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5,"top": 0.25}
            size_hint: 0.15, 0.15
            font_size: 11
            #on_press: root.###()

        Button:
            id: bck
            text: "Back"
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.80,"top": 0.25}
            size_hint: 0.15, 0.15
            font_size: 11
            on_release: 
                app.root.current = "StartScreen"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"




<PoliceNearMe>:
    name: "PoliceNearMe"
    FloatLayout:
        
        MapView:
            lat:-25.4878
            lon:25.98517 
            zoom: 5
            on_zoom:
                self.zoom = 5 if self.zoom < 5 else self.zoom
            double_tap_zoom:True
            
            Button:
                text: "Back"
                size_hint: 0.15, 0.15
                pos_hint:{"x": 0.5, "top": 0.25}
                font_size: 11
                on_release: 
                    app.root.current = "StartScreen"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
            MapMarkerPopup:
                source: 'marker2.png'
                lat:-32.42247
                lon:26.78883
                Button:
                    text:'KOLOMANE'
                    color: 0,0,0,1
                    size: self.texture_size
                    size_hint: None, None
                    on_press: root.button_on()
                    on_release: 
                        #:import webbrowser webbrowser
                        webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=KOLOMANE+police+station&travelmode=driving')
                        root.button_off()

                    
                    Image:
                        id: MapButton
                        source: 'MapMarker Button up.png' 
                        center_x: self.parent.center_x
                        center_y: self.parent.center_y
                        size: 270, 200
                        
                        size_hint: None, None
                        
                        Label:
                            text:'KOLOMANE'
                            font_size: 14
                            color: 0.3,0.3,0.3,1
                            center_x: self.parent.center_x
                            center_y: self.parent.center_y
<EmergencyNumbers>:
    name: "EmergencyNumbers"
    
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        
        Button:
            text: "Police"
            
        Button:
            text: "Medical"
            
        Button:
            text: "Fire"
            
        Button:
            text: "Animal"
            
        Button:
            text: "Poison"
            
        Button:
            text: "Child Abuse"
            
        Button:
            text: "Suicide"
            
        
        Button:
            text: "Back"
            size_hint: 0.15, 0.15
            font_size: 11
            on_release: 
                app.root.current = "StartScreen"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
```

NOTE: the kv file contains A LOT more mapmarkers, i just included one here for simplicity sake

## Logcat

```
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of main
08-01 12:09:54.291 31780 31780 I python  : [INFO   ] [WindowSDL   ] No running App found, exit.
08-01 12:11:00.050 31854 31882 I python  : Initializing Python for Android
08-01 12:11:00.050 31854 31882 I python  : Setting additional env vars from p4a_env_vars.txt
08-01 12:11:00.056 31854 31882 I python  : Changing directory to the one provided by ANDROID_ARGUMENT
08-01 12:11:00.056 31854 31882 I python  : /data/user/0/org.mccoy.crimewhereza/files/app
08-01 12:11:00.056 31854 31882 I python  : Preparing to initialize python
08-01 12:11:00.056 31854 31882 I python  : _python_bundle dir exists
08-01 12:11:00.056 31854 31882 I python  : calculated paths to be...
08-01 12:11:00.056 31854 31882 I python  : /data/user/0/org.mccoy.crimewhereza/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip:/data/user/0/org.mccoy.crimewhereza/files/app/_python_bundle/modules
08-01 12:11:00.057 31854 31882 I python  : set wchar paths...
08-01 12:11:00.268 31854 31882 I python  : Initialized python
08-01 12:11:00.268 31854 31882 I python  : AND: Init threads
08-01 12:11:00.271 31854 31882 I python  : testing python print redirection
08-01 12:11:00.273 31854 31882 I python  : Android path ['.', '/data/user/0/org.mccoy.crimewhereza/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip', '/data/user/0/org.mccoy.crimewhereza/files/app/_python_bundle/modules', '/data/user/0/org.mccoy.crimewhereza/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages']
08-01 12:11:00.274 31854 31882 I python  : os.environ is environ({'PATH': '/sbin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/vendor/bin:/vendor/xbin', 'DOWNLOAD_CACHE': '/data/cache', 'ANDROID_BOOTLOGO': '1', 'ANDROID_ROOT': '/system', 'ANDROID_ASSETS': '/system/app', 'ANDROID_DATA': '/data', 'ANDROID_STORAGE': '/storage', 'EXTERNAL_STORAGE': '/storage/self/primary', 'ASEC_MOUNTPOINT': '/mnt/asec', 'BOOTCLASSPATH': '/system/framework/core-oj.jar:/system/framework/core-libart.jar:/system/framework/conscrypt.jar:/system/framework/okhttp.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/legacy-test.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar:/system/framework/android.hidl.base-V1.0-java.jar:/system/framework/android.hidl.manager-V1.0-java.jar:/system/framework/radio_interactor_common.jar', 'SYSTEMSERVERCLASSPATH': '/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/ethernet-service.jar:/system/framework/wifi-service.jar:/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar', 'EMULATED_STORAGE': '/storage/self/emulated', 'PHYSICAL_STORAGE': '/storage/sdcard0', 'USBDISK_STORAGE': '/storage/usbdisk', 'ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote': '8', 'ANDROID_ENTRYPOINT': 'main.pyc', 'ANDROID_ARGUMENT': '/data/user/0/org.mccoy.crimewhereza/files/app', 'ANDROID_APP_PATH': '/data/user/0/org.mccoy.crimewhereza/files/app', 'ANDROID_PRIVATE': '/data/user/0/org.mccoy.crimewhereza/files', 'ANDROID_UNPACK': '/data/user/0/org.mccoy.crimewhereza/files/app', 'PYTHONHOME': '/data/user/0/org.mccoy.crimewhereza/files/app', 'PYTHONPATH': '/data/user/0/org.mccoy.crimewhereza/files/app:/data/user/0/org.mccoy.crimewhereza/files/app/lib', 'PYTHONOPTIMIZE': '2', 'P4A_BOOTSTRAP': 'SDL2', 'PYTHON_NAME': 'python', 'P4A_IS_WINDOWED': 'True', 'P4A_ORIENTATION': 'portrait', 'P4A_NUMERIC_VERSION': 'None', 'P4A_MINSDK': '21', 'LC_CTYPE': 'C.UTF-8'})
08-01 12:11:00.274 31854 31882 I python  : Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
08-01 12:11:00.274 31854 31882 I python  : AND: Ran string
08-01 12:11:00.274 31854 31882 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
08-01 12:11:00.686 31854 31882 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/org.mccoy.crimewhereza/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_21-08-01_3.txt
08-01 12:11:00.686 31854 31882 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
08-01 12:11:00.688 31854 31882 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/org.mccoy.crimewhereza/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/__init__.pyc"
08-01 12:11:00.688 31854 31882 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.1 (default, Aug  1 2021, 01:16:47) 
08-01 12:11:00.688 31854 31882 I python  : [Clang 8.0.2 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/clang 40173bab62ec7462
08-01 12:11:00.689 31854 31882 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at ""
08-01 12:11:03.199 31854 31882 I python  : [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
08-01 12:11:04.209 31854 31882 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
08-01 12:11:04.332 31854 31882 I python  : [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
08-01 12:11:05.350 31854 31882 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
08-01 12:11:05.419 31854 31882 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
08-01 12:11:05.423 31854 31882 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
08-01 12:11:05.424 31854 31882 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.2 v1.r21p0-01rel0.23d6ddb7b7b473615078236961ef3863'>
08-01 12:11:05.425 31854 31882 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'ARM'>
08-01 12:11:05.426 31854 31882 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Mali-T820'>
08-01 12:11:05.427 31854 31882 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
08-01 12:11:05.428 31854 31882 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
08-01 12:11:05.429 31854 31882 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
08-01 12:11:05.473 31854 31882 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
08-01 12:11:05.475 31854 31882 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard allowed, single mode, docked
```

## Buildozer spec file

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = CrimeWhereZA

# (str) Package name
package.name = crimewhereza

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.McCoy

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,txt,csv

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0rc4,kivy_garden.mapview,openssl,requests,urllib3,chardet,idna

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 2.0.0

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (string) Presplash animation using Lottie format.
# see https://lottiefiles.com/ for examples and https://airbnb.design/lottie/
# for general documentation.
# Lottie files can be created using various tools, like Adobe After Effect or Synfig.
#android.presplash_lottie = "path/to/lottie/file.json"

# (str) Adaptive icon of the application (used if Android API level is 26+ at runtime)
#icon.adaptive_foreground.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_fg.png
#icon.adaptive_background.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_bg.png

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (list) features (adds uses-feature -tags to manifest)
#android.features = android.hardware.usb.host

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 27

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (bool) Enable AndroidX support. Enable when 'android.gradle_dependencies'
# contains an 'androidx' package, or any package from Kotlin source.
# android.enable_androidx requires android.api >= 28
#android.enable_androidx = False

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_packaging_options =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Android logcat only display log for activity's pid
#android.logcat_pid_only = False

# (str) Android additional adb arguments
#android.adb_args = -H host.docker.internal

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

# (bool) enables Android auto backup feature (Android API >=23)
android.allow_backup = True

# (str) XML file for custom backup rules (see official auto backup documentation)
# android.backup_rules =

# (str) If you need to insert variables into your AndroidManifest.xml file,
# you can do so with the manifestPlaceholders property.
# This property takes a map of key-value pairs. (via a string)
# Usage example : android.manifest_placeholders = [myCustomUrl:\"org.kivy.customurl\"]
# android.manifest_placeholders = [:]

# (bool) disables the compilation of py to pyc/pyo files when packaging
# android.no-compile-pyo = True

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android URL to use for checkout
#p4a.url =

# (str) python-for-android fork to use in case if p4a.url is not specified, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =

# Control passing the --use-setup-py vs --ignore-setup-py to p4a
# "in the future" --use-setup-py is going to be the default behaviour in p4a, right now it is not
# Setting this to false will pass --ignore-setup-py, true will pass --use-setup-py
# NOTE: this is general setuptools integration, having pyproject.toml is enough, no need to generate
# setup.py if you're using Poetry, but you need to add "toml" to source.include_exts.
#p4a.setup_py = false


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.10.0

# (bool) Whether or not to sign the code
ios.codesign.allowed = false

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) The development team to use for signing the debug version
#ios.codesign.development_team.debug = <hexstring>

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s

# (str) The development team to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.development_team.release = <hexstring>

# (str) URL pointing to .ipa file to be installed
# This option should be defined along with `display_image_url` and `full_size_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.app_url =

# (str) URL pointing to an icon (57x57px) to be displayed during download
# This option should be defined along with `app_url` and `full_size_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.display_image_url =

# (str) URL pointing to a large icon (512x512px) to be used by iTunes
# This option should be defined along with `app_url` and `display_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.full_size_image_url =


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Comment: What happens if you try to run a simple kivy app that doesn't try to load any kv and just returns (say) a Button?

Comment: i ran this exact example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-working-with-buttons-in-kivy/ and it worked perfectly... why is that? should i scrap the kv file all together?

Comment: @inclement forgot to tag sorry!

Comment: No need to scrap it, but add to it step by step until it breaks to find the problem. For instance, if you are generating a huge number of widgets perhaps your device is just doing it so slowly it looks like it's hanging.

Answer (score 1):

I had such a problem and the reason i got , is you need to include `PIL` library (named as pillow) in `buildozer.spec` file in requirements section :

```
requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0rc4,pillow==9.2.0,kivy_garden.mapview,openssl,requests,urllib3,chardet,idna
```